# elif raises a syntax error, but if does not

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I get an error when I try to change an "if" to an "elif." The code works perfectly when I'm using an if, but raises a syntax error if I try to use "elif" instead. I need to use "elif" because I only want one of the if statements to run, not both. This code works fine:

```
guess_row=0
guess_col=0
ship_location=0
number_of_attempts=3

guess_location = input("Guess :").split(",")
guess_row,guess_col = int(guess_location[0]),int(guess_location[1])
if guess_row not in range(1,6):
    print("Out of range1.")
print(guess_location)
print(ship_location)         
if guess_col not in range(1,6):
    print("Out of range2.")
print(guess_location)
print(ship_location)
if ship_location == guess_location:
    print("You sunk my battleship! You win!")
else:
    print ("You missed!")
    print ("You have " + str(number_of_attempts-1) + " attempt(s) left!")
    print ("Try again!")
    number_of_attempts-=1
```

But if I change the 2nd or 3rd "if" to "elif":

```
guess_row=0
guess_col=0
ship_location=0
number_of_attempts=3

guess_location = input("Guess :").split(",")
guess_row,guess_col = int(guess_location[0]),int(guess_location[1])
if guess_row not in range(1,6):
    print("Out of range1.")
print(guess_location)
print(ship_location)         
elif guess_col not in range(1,6):
    print("Out of range2.")
print(guess_location)
print(ship_location)
elif ship_location == guess_location:
    print("You sunk my battleship! You win!")
else:
    print ("You missed!")
    print ("You have " + str(number_of_attempts-1) + " attempt(s) left!")
    print ("Try again!")
    number_of_attempts-=1
```

I get a syntax error. Help?

Comment: The print statements you have end the `if/elif/else` scope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`elif` is not a separate statement. `elif` is an option part of an existing `if` statement.

As such, you can only use `elif` *directly* after an `if` block:

```
if sometest:
    indented lines
    forming a block
elif anothertest:
    another block
```

In your code, however, the `elif` does *not* directly follow a block already part of the `if` statement. You have lines in between that are no longer part of the block because they are not indented to the `if` block level anymore:

```
if guess_row not in range(1,6):
    print("Out of range1.")  # part of the block
print(guess_location)        # NOT part of the block, so the block ended
print(ship_location)         
elif guess_col not in range(1,6):
```

This doesn't matter to *separate* `if` statements; the un-indented `print()` statements are executed between the `if` blocks.

You'll need to move those `print()` functions to be run *after* the `if...elif...else` statemement:

```
if guess_row not in range(1,6):
    print("Out of range1.")
elif guess_col not in range(1,6):
    print("Out of range2.")
elif ship_location == guess_location:
    print("You sunk my battleship! You win!")
else:
    print ("You missed!")
    print ("You have " + str(number_of_attempts-1) + " attempt(s) left!")
    print ("Try again!")
    number_of_attempts-=1

print(guess_location)
print(ship_location)
```

or fix their indentation to be part of the `if` and `elif` blocks.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed it per your recommendations, and now it works perfectly!